# Web scraping using Beautifulsoup/Selenium unable to pull div class using find or find_all

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to webscrape form the website https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Monsters%20List#content and having some issues.

My first script I tried kept returning an empty list when finding by div and class name, which I believe is do to the site using Javascript? But a little uncertain if that is the case or not.

Here was my first attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get('https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Monsters%20List#content')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

card = soup.find_all("div", class_='card')

print(card)
```

This one returns an empty list so then I tired to use Selenium and scrape with that. Here is that script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

url='https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Monsters%20List#content'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\Windows\System32\geckodriver')
driver.get(url)

page = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(page,'html.parser')
```

Starting the script with that I then tried all 3 of these different options (individually ran these, just listed them here together for simplicity sake):

```
for card in body.find('div', {"class":"card"}):
    print(card.text)

print(card)
    
for card in body.find_all('div', {"class":"card"}):
    print(card.text)

print(card)        

card = body.find_all('div', {"class":"card"})

print(card)
```

All of them return the same error message:
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Where am I going wrong here?

Edit:

Fazul thank you for your input on this I guess I should be more specific. I was more looking to get the contents of each card. For example, the card has a "body" class and within that body class there are many fields that is the data I am looking to extract. Maybe I am misunderstanding your script and what you stated. Here is a screen shot to maybe help specify my question a bit more to what content I am looking to extract.

[image]

So everything that would be under the body i.e. name, title, subtitle, etc.. Those were the texts I was trying to extract.

Answer (score 0):

That page is being loaded by JavaScript. So `beautifulsoup` will not work in this case. You have to use Selenium.

And the element that you are looking for - *`<div>` with class name as `card`* show up **only when you click on the drop-down arrow**. Since you are not doing any `click` event in your code, you get an empty result.

- Use selenium to click the `<div>` with class name as `dropdown-toggle`. That click event loads the `<div class='card'>`
- Then you can scrape the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

Since the page is loaded by JavaScript, you have to use Selenium.

## My solution As follows:

Every card has a link as shown: [image: imge]

Use BeautifulSoup to get the link for each card, Then open each link using Selenium in **headless mode** because it is also loaded by JavaScript.

Then you get the data you need for each card using BeautifulSoup

## Working code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager import driver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriver, ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Monsters%20List#content")
page = driver.page_source

# Wait until the page is loaded
sleep(13)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

# Get all card urls
urls = soup.find_all("div", {"class":"header inapp-hide single-hide"})

cards_list = []
for url in urls:
    card = {}
    card_url = url.a["href"]
    card_link = f'https://roll20.net{card_url}#content'

    # Open chrom in headless mode
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
    driver.get(card_link )
    page = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    card["name"] = soup.select_one(".name").text.split("\n")[1]
    card["subtitle"] = soup.select_one(".subtitle").text
    # Do the same to get all card detealis 

    cards_list.append(card)
    driver.quit()
```

## Library you need to install

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

This library open chrome driver without the need to geckodriver and get up to date driver for you.

Answer (score 0):

https://roll20.net/compendium/compendium/getList?bookName=dnd5e&pageName=Monsters%20List&_=1630747796747

u can get the json data from this link instead just parse it and get the data you need